# Sending TCP and Ethernet packets

Tags: python, sockets

I want to send TCP and Ethernet packets from one machine to another.

I want to create a script that will start multiple packet streams (TCP, Ethernet) to send packets.

To do this in Python, can I simply create separate sockets (for each kind of stream), and use the send() function?

Is there any recommended way to start multiple packet streams in Python?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to send arbitrary TCP packets that you craft, or do you want to open a TCP connection? Also, what do you mean by "packet streams"? If you just send raw Ethernet packets, any multiplexing and demultiplexing into separate streams is entirely your responsibility. Maybe if you can explain what you want to do this for, it will be easier to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to send arbitrary TCP, and ethernet packets periodically (every 20 ms). I was wondering if by opening two separate sockets, I can send TCP and ethernet packets at the same time.